# Which is the best approach to handle data driven test using selenium?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to identify the best approach for my data-driven testing using cucumber. There are multiple ways for handling data in cucumber:

1. Data Table
2. Scenario outline
3. CSV
4. JSON

Personally I think scenario outline and data table are quite good, if we want to handle limited data because we don't need separate data reader code to retrieve data from the JSON and CSV files.

Currently, I argued with one of my teammates to not go with JSON or CSV approach until its seriously required. Because I think CSV is required when you want to handle a huge set of data. People are forcing to use CSV or JSON approach just to reduce the size of the feature file and also saying the data table is not java safe. Can someone please help me out clear my doubt.

Also is it not approach to handle data table as a `List<Map<String, String>>` :

```
List<Map<String, String>> datablealues= DataTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
```

Comment: I am not sure why they feel `data table is not java safe`. It all depends on the way you use the data, if you have any sensitive data you can always use encryption mechanism (by that way only people with Security Key can decrypt and access the sensitive data).  I would prefer using Data table only for repetitive step and examples tables to repeat the entire scenario. If you are sure whether the data size will change in future/source of data is from another system then you can relay on the external files (json preferable)

Comment: i am wondered, how you are using CSV/JSON with cucumber?

Comment: To achieve data-driven testing we can use JSON /CSV along with POJO classes to represent data. There are so many free articles available to start with this approach